# Removing syntactic sugar: List comprehension in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension, lazy-evaluation

Can I unsugar list comprehension in this expression:

```
[(i,j) | i <- [1..4], j <- [i+1..4]]
```

This is the output:

```
[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]
```

How can I, with map, filter and so on, write that piece of code?

**edit**

Here an other:

```
[(i,j,k) | i <- [1..6], j <- [i+1..6],k <- [j+1..6]]
```

This is the output:

```
[(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,2,5),(1,2,6),(1,3,4),(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,4,5),(1,4,6),(1,5,6),(2,3,4),(2,3,5),(2,3,6),(2,4,5),(2,4,6),(2,5,6),(3,4,5),(3,4,6),(3,5,6),(4,5,6)]
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

List comprehensions (in fact, Monad comprehensions) can be desugared into `do` notation.

```haskell
do i <- [1..4]
   j <- [i+1..4]
   return (i,j)
```

Which can be desugared as usual:

```haskell
[1..4]   >>= \i ->
[i+1..4] >>= \j ->
return (i,j)
```

It is well known that `a >>= \x -> return b` is the same as `fmap (\x -> b) a`. So an intermediate desugaring step:

```haskell
[1..4] >>= \i -> 
fmap (\j -> (i,j)) [i+1..4]
```

For lists, `(>>=) = flip concatMap`, and `fmap = map`

```haskell
(flip concatMap) [1..4] (\i -> map (\j -> (i,j) [i+1..4])
```

`flip` simply switches the order of the inputs.

```haskell
concatMap (\i -> map (\j -> (i,j)) [i+1..4]) [1..4]
```

And this is how you wind up with Tsuyoshi's answer.

---

The second can similarly be desugared into:

```haskell
concatMap (\i ->
  concatMap (\j ->
    map       (\k ->
      (i,j,k))
    [j+1..6])
  [i+1..6])
[1..6]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
concatMap (\i -> map (\j -> (i, j)) [i+1 .. 4]) [1 .. 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

The desugared code is:

```
concatMap (\i -> concatMap (\j -> (i, j) : []) [i+1..4]) [1..4]
```

Which can be refactored to Tsuyoshi Ito's answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is yet another translation scheme, it is due to Wadler, as far as I know.

This would give:

```
let
    lc_outer (x:xs) = let lc_inner (y:ys) = (x,y) : lc_inner ys
                          lc_inner []     = lc_outer xs
                      in lc_inner [x+1.. 4]
    lc_outer [] = []
in  lc_outer [1..4]
```

This translation avoids needless construction of singleton lists in the innermost level that would need to get flattened with concatMap later.