# Generating tuples of grid coordinates in Haskell

Tags: haskell, grid-layout

I want to write a function that generates a list of tuples containing the coordinates of an n by n grid.

For example:

```
> genGrid 2
[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)]
> genGrid 3
[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
```

I know I can generate a diagonal by doing the following:

```
genDiagonal n = zip [0..] [0..n-1]
```

I am thinking there is a fairly simple way to do this, perhaps a variant of my diagonal function, but am coming up blank.

Comment: `[(x, y) | x <- [0..n-1], y <- [0..n-1]]` for row-major, or `[(y, x) ...]` for column-major.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029046/) which generates the exact desired output (although it is a different question).

Comment: `grid d n = sequence $ replicate d [0..n]` will generate a `d` dimensional grid of size `n`. This can be partially evaluated to get a 2 dimensional grid `2dGrid = grid 2`.

Comment: this is also almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119730/cartesian-product, which gives a bunch of alternate solns.  My favorite is `(,) <$> [0..x] <*> [0..x]`

Answer (score 6):

The [`range`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Ix.html) function does this:

```
Data.Ix> range ((0, 0), (2, 3))
[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]
```