# How does haskell create a new list from another list?

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, lazy-evaluation

Suppose we have a list

```
x = [1..10]
```

and we intend to create another list y using this in this manner :

```
y= [a|a<-x]
```

So while creating the list `y` from `x`, it accesses each element of `x`( from 1 to 10) and inserts it in `y` in the same order. As a list in haskell is singly linked list, we can insert a new element only at its head. So first it inserts 1 to `[]` & we have `[1]`. Then it inserts 2 to its head & so we have `[2,1]`. Then it inserts 3 & we have `[3,2,1]` & so on. So ultimately we should get `y` as `[10,9..1]`. But instead we get `y` as `[1..10]`. Why is that so?

Comment: This is a good explanation on how to desugar the list comprehension syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8029698/1013393

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it "inserts" them at list's tail *(while the list is being built),* not head (cf. "tail recursion modulo cons"):

```
[a | a <- [1..10]]     ==
[a | a <- (1:[2..10])] ==      -- [a | a <- ([1] ++ [2..10])]
1 : [a | a <- [2..10]]         -- [1] ++ [a | a <- [2..10]]
```

This is because

```
[a | a <- (xs ++ ys)]  ==  [a | a <- xs] ++ [a | a <- ys]
```

and

```
[a | a <- ys]  ==  ys
```

Answer (score 6):

The way you are thinking about list comprehensions is not quite correct. When you see a comprehension

```
y <- [f a | a <- x]
```

you shouldn't think about the successive result being added to the front of an (initially empty) result list.

Instead, think of each `f a` being added to the front of the result of running the list comprehension on the rest of `x`. That is,

```
[f a | a <- x:xs] == f x : [f a | a <- xs]
```

This is a recursive approach - by assuming that the result list exists for the tail of the list, you can add the next result to the front of it.

Answer (score 4):

It's instructive to look at exactly how list comprehensions desugar to monadic computations, rather than use the intuition for how they work.

```
[a | a <- [1..3]] == do {a <- [1..3]; return a}   -- desugared comprehension
                  == [1..3] >>= return a          -- desugared do
                  == concat (map return [1..3])   -- definition of >>=
                  == concat [[1], [2], [3]]       -- defintiion of return
                  == [1,2,3]                      -- definition of concat
```