# Empty list generators

Tags: haskell

How list generators are handled by Haskell? Specifically, why does this

```
f n = [x:xs | x <- [1..n], xs <- []]
```

yields empty list? What is `xs` in `x:xs` in every 'iteration'?

Comment: There is no answer to "What is `xs` in `x:xs` in every 'iteration'?" because there are no "iterations" of `x:xs`. Meditate on this expression: `[undefined | _ <- []] == []`.

Comment: @duplode gave a great answer regarding why it doesn't work. But I assume, you wanted to create lists of lists each containing a single element; which you can do with `f n = [x:xs | x <- [1..n], xs <- [[]] ]`

Comment: That creates single-element lists, but why would you do it that way? Just `f n = [[x] | x <- [1..n]]`, or `f n = map pure [1..n]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The zoomed-out answer is that...

```
[x:xs | x <- [1..n], xs <- []]
```

... consists of all possible lists generated by picking an element (`x`) from `[1..n]` plus an element (`xs`) from `[]` and prepending one to the other. Since there are no elements in `[]`, the number of lists that can be generated in this way is zero.

The zoomed-in answer is that [list comprehensions are sugar for the list monad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8029046/2751851), and so this...

```
[x:xs | x <- [1..n], xs <- []]
```

... is equivalent to...

```
do
    x <- [1..n]
    xs <- []
    return (x:xs)
```

... that is (after desugaring do-notation)...

```
[1..n] >>= \x ->
[] >>= \xs ->
return (x:xs)

-- Or, without the line breaks:
[1..n] >>= \x -> [] >>= \xs -> return (x:xs)
```

... that is (after substituting the definitions of `(>>=)` and `return` for the list monad):

```
concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\xs -> [x:xs]) []) [1..n]
```

`concatMap` (which, as the name suggests, is merely `map` followed by `concat`) on an empty list gives an empty list, and so it becomes...

```
concatMap (\x -> []) [1..n]
```

... which amounts to replacing each element of `[1..n]` with an empty list and then `concat`-ing the result, which produces an empty list.