# Haskell Monad - How does Monad on list work?

Tags: list, haskell, monads

In order to understand Monad, I came up with the following definitions:

```
class Applicative' f where
 purea :: a -> f a
 app :: f (a->b) -> f a -> f b

class Applicative' m =>  Monadd m where
 (>>|) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

instance Applicative' [] where
 purea x = [x]
 app gs xs = [g x | g <- gs, x <- xs]

instance Monadd [] where
 (>>|) xs f = [ y | x <-xs, y <- f x]
```

It works as expected:

```
(>>|) [1,2,3,4] (\x->[(x+1)])
[2,3,4,5]
```

I am not sure how it is working though. 
For example:

```
[ y | y <- [[1],[2]]]
[[1],[2]]
```

How does application `(\x->([x+1])` to each list element of `[1,2,3]` result in `[2,3,4]` and not `[[2],[3],[4]]`

Or quite simply my confusion seems to stem from not understanding how this statement `[ y | x <-xs, y <- f x]` actually works

Comment: You wrote it yourself. `(>>|) xs f = [ y | x <-xs, y <- f x]`. This is **not** "application ... to each element" of the original list, this is something else. Application to each element would be `map f xs = [f x |  x <- xs]`.

Comment: Yes, looks like I have not understood how `[ y | x <-xs, y <- f x]` works

Comment: It should be helpful to write down the types of x, xs, y and f x in that expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wadler](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/marktoberdorf/baastad.pdf), [School of Haskell](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/13-the-list-monad), [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads), [HaskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monads_as_containers), [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-list-a-monad-in-Haskell-and-how-does-one-understand-it-as-a-monad) and many more describe the list monad.

Compare:

- `(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b` for lists with
- [`concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) for `m = []`.

The regular `(>>=)` bind operator has the arguments flipped, but is otherwise just an infix `concatMap`.

> Or quite simply my confusion seems to stem from not understanding how this statement actually works:
>
> ```
> (>>|) xs f = [ y | x <- xs, y <- f x ]
> ```

Since list comprehensions are equivalent to the Monad instance for lists, this definition is kind of cheating. You're basically saying that something is a Monadd in the way that it's a Monad, so you're left with two problems: Understanding list comprehensions, and still understanding Monad.

List comprehensions can be de-sugared for a better understanding:

- [Removing syntactic sugar: List comprehension in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029046/removing-syntactic-sugar-list-comprehension-in-haskell)

In your case, the statement could be written in a number of other ways:

- Using do-notation:

  ```
  (>>|) xs f = do x <- xs
                  y <- f x
                  return y
  ```
- De-sugared into using the `(>>=)` operator:

  ```
  (>>|) xs f = xs >>= \x ->
               f x >>= \y ->
               return y
  ```
- This can be shortened (one rewrite per line):

  ```
    (>>|) xs f = xs >>= \x -> f x >>= \y -> return y -- eta-reduction
  ≡ (>>|) xs f = xs >>= \x -> f x >>= return         -- monad identity
  ≡ (>>|) xs f = xs >>= \x -> f x                    -- eta-reduction
  ≡ (>>|) xs f = xs >>= f                            -- prefix operator
  ≡ (>>|) xs f = (>>=) xs f                          -- point-free
  ≡ (>>|) = (>>=)
  ```

So from using list comprehensions, you haven't really declared a new definition, you're just relying on the existing one. If you wanted, you could instead define your `instance Monadd []` without relying on existing Monad instances or list comprehensions:

- Using `concatMap`:

  ```
  instance Monadd [] where
    (>>|) xs f = concatMap f xs
  ```
- Spelling that out a little more:

  ```
  instance Monadd [] where
    (>>|) xs f = concat (map f xs)
  ```
- Spelling that out even more:

  ```
  instance Monadd [] where
    (>>|) [] f = []
    (>>|) (x:xs) f = let ys = f x in ys ++ ((>>|) xs f)
  ```

The Monadd type class should have something similar to `return`. I'm not sure why it's missing.

Comment: there is no cheating though. LCs happen to be equivalent to the monadic code, but [are defined separately](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11).

Answer (score 3):

Monads are often easier understood with the “mathematical definition”, than with the methods of the Haskell standard class. Namely,

```
class Applicative' m => Monadd m where
  join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

Note that you can implement the standard version in terms of this, vice versa:

```
join mma = mma >>= id

ma >>= f = join (fmap f ma)
```

For lists, `join` (aka `concat`) is particularly simple:

```
join :: [[a]] -> [a]
join xss = [x | xs <- xss, x <- xs]  -- xss::[[a]], xs::[a]
-- join [[1],[2]] ≡ [1,2]
```

For the example you find confusing, you'd have

```
[1,2,3,4] >>= \x->[(x+1)]
  ≡   join $ fmap (\x->[(x+1)]) [1,2,3,4]
  ≡   join [[1+1], [2+1], [3+1], [4+1]]
  ≡   join [[2],[3],[4],[5]]
  ≡   [2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: But how does it work in terms of the `Applicative` and `Monadd` instances that I have defined? Or rather how is `join` implemented in terms of `purea` `app` and `(>>|)`?

Comment: Well, by joining the elementwise-apply result. I think you didn't realise that the list comprehension does that (see edit, I showed how `join` can be implemented with a comprehension).

Answer (score 2):

[List comprehensions](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) are just like nested loops:

```
   xs >>| foo = [ y | x <- xs, y <- foo x]

--            =   for x in xs:
--                         for y in (foo x):
--                               yield y
```

Thus we have

```
[1,2,3,4] >>| (\x -> [x, x+10])
=
[ y | x <- [1,2,3,4], y <- (\x -> [x, x+10]) x]
=
[ y | x <- [1] ++ [2,3,4], y <- [x, x+10]]
=
[ y | x <- [1], y <- [x, x+10]] ++ [ y | x <- [2,3,4], y <- [x, x+10]]  -- (*)
=
[ y |           y <- [1, 1+10]]   ++ [ y | x <- [2,3,4], y <- [x, x+10]]
=
[ y | y <- [1]] ++ [ y | y <- [11]] ++ [ y | x <- [2,3,4], y <- [x, x+10]]
=
[1] ++ [11] ++ [ y | x <- [2,3,4], y <- [x, x+10]]
=
[1, 11] ++ [2, 12] ++ [ y | x <- [3,4], y <- [x, x+10]]
=
[1, 11] ++ [2, 12] ++ [3, 13] ++ [ y | x <- [4], y <- [x, x+10]]
=
[1, 11] ++ [2, 12] ++ [3, 13] ++ [4, 14]
```

The crucial step is marked `(*)`. You can take it as the definition of what list comprehensions *are*.

A special case is when the `foo` function returns a singleton list, like in your question. Then it is indeed tantamount to *mapping*, as each element in the input list is turned into *one* (transformed) element in the output list.

But list comprehensions are more powerful. An input element can also be turned conditionally into no elements (working as a *filter*), or several elements:

```
  [ a,          [a1, a2] ++        concat [ [a1, a2],         [  a1, a2,
    b,    ==>   [b1]     ++    ==           [b1],        ==      b1,
    c,          []       ++                 [],
    d ]         [d1, d2]                    [d1, d2] ]           d1, d2  ]
```

The above is equivalent to

```
    concat (map foo [a,b,c,d]) 
    =  
    foo a ++ foo b ++ foo c ++ foo d
```

for some appropriate `foo`.

`concat` is list monad's `join`, and `map` is list monad's `fmap`. In general, for any monad,

```
    m >>= foo  =  join (fmap foo m)
```

The essence of Monad is: from each entity "in" a "structure", conditionally producing new elements in the same kind of structure, and splicing them in-place:

```
[     a     ,  b   ,  c  ,    d      ]
    /   \      |      |     /   \
[  [a1, a2] , [b1] ,  [] , [d1, d2]  ]  -- fmap foo    = [foo x | x <- xs]
                                        --             =     [y | x <- xs, y <- [foo x]]
[   a1, a2  ,  b1  ,        d1, d2   ]  -- join (fmap foo) = [y | x <- xs, y <-  foo x ]
```