# In filterM, why is `return (if b then x:ys else ys)` evaluated once after all the lists are created?

Tags: haskell, monads

```
filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM p [] = return []
filterM p (x:xs) = do b <- p x
                      ys <- filterM p xs
                      return (if b then x:ys else ys)
```

and

```
> filterM (\x -> [True,False]) [1,2,3]
[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,3],[1],[2,3],[2],[3],[]]
```

Is `return  (if b then x:ys else ys)`  evaluated  each time a list is created? Is yes, why isn't the result `[[1,2,3]],[[1,2]],[[1,3]],[[1]],[[2,3]],[[2]],[[3]],[[]]`?

Does the result `[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,3],[1],[2,3],[2],[3],[]]` imply that `return (if b then x:ys else ys)`  is  evaluated once after all the lists are created?

Comment: Because the bind operator is `concatMap` so it concatenates the results.

Comment: Your suggested result is invalid syntax: `[[x],[y]]` is a list of lists, `[[x]],[[y]]` does not mean anything. At best, we have `[[[x]],[[y]]]` which would be a list-of-lists-of-lists, but that has another type wrt `[[x],[y]]`.

Comment: [for lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51178620/849891), `join [a,b,c,...,n] == a ++ b ++ c ++ ... ++ n`, hence `join [[x],[],[y]] = [x] ++ [] ++ [y] = [x,y]`. how is this relevant? because `xs >>= foo = join (fmap foo xs)` (and hence, `= join (map foo xs) = concat (map foo xs) = concatMap foo xs`). `return x = [x]` "injects" an element `x` into the overall result (list). and `[]` injects nothing into the overall result (list).

Answer (score 7):

**In short**: because the bind function `(>>=)` for the `instance Monad []` is implement with `concatMap`, not `map`.

We can desugar the `do` block as:

```
filterM ::  Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM p [] = return []
filterM p (x:xs) =  p x >>= \b -> (filterM p xs >>= \ys -> return (if b then x:ys else ys))
```

For `m ~ []`, the `>>=` function is equivalent to `flip concatMap`, and `return x` is equivalent to `[x]`, so that means that we can transform this, for a list, into:

```
filterM ::  (a -> [Bool]) -> [a] -> [[a]]
filterM p [] = [[]]
filterM p (x:xs) = concatMap (\b -> concatMap (\ys -> [if b then (x:ys) else ys]) (filterM p xs)) (p x)
```

A `concatMap (\x -> [f x])` is equivalent to `map f`, since the concatenation of all these singleton lists will result in a list that contains the outcomes of `f` for all elements in the given list.

It thus means that the above function is equivalent to:

```
filterM ::  (a -> [Bool]) -> [a] -> [[a]]
filterM p [] = [[]]
filterM p (x:xs) = concatMap (\b -> map (\ys -> if b then (x:ys) else ys) (filterM p xs)) (p x)
```

If `p` is `\_ -> [True, False]`, it thus means we can replace `(p x)` with `[True, False]`, and thus obtain:

```
concatMap (\b -> map (\ys -> if b then (x:ys) else ys) (filterM p xs)) [True, False]
```

This thus means that `concatMap` is the concatenation of two lists: one where `b` is `True`, and one where `b` is `False`, like:

```
map (\ys -> (x:ys)) (filterM p xs) ++ map (\ys -> ys) (filterM p xs)
```

The first `map` will thus prepend all the lists from `filterM p xs` with `x` whereas the second one will not. The above expression is thus equivalent to:

```
map (x:) (filterM p xs) ++ filterM p xs
```

if `filterM p xs` contains the powerset of `xs`, then the above expression will thus contain the powerset of `(x:xs)`.